# Im having and issue with printing the result of my code, no matter what I have tried im not back to get it to print my overspending or underspending

Tags: python

[Assignment description, code below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpPow.png)

Im having and issue with printing the result of my code, no matter what I have tried im not back to get it to print my overspending or underspending

```html
    budget = float(input('Enter the allocated budget for this month: '))
    expenses = 0
    check = 0
    while check >= 0:
        check = float(input('Enter a cost (<0 stops the loop): '))
        if check != -1:
            expenses += check
            balance = budget - expenses
    if balance < 0:
        print ("Your expenses are within budget by $")
    else:
        print ("Your expenses are over budget by $")
```

Comment: You are not passing the `balance` to the print. Search for python string formatting.

Comment: It works for me to the extent that the prints show on screen. Do you see the input prompts? Do you see anything after that?

Comment: `if check != -1` should be `if check >= 0`

Comment: There's no need to assign `balance` each time through the loop. Do it once after you've calculated the total expenses.

Comment: Please paste information here as text, not images. And there's no reason to format Python code as HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As Myousefi said, you are not passing the variable **balance** to the print command (I'm considering you refer Overspending or underspending to that variable)

You can print string texts using "" or variables of different kind (int, float, strings itselfs), or both. However, you have to separate them with commas (,). Take a look on this:

```
a="world"
print("Hello",a,"!")
```

You will get this

```
>>>Hello world !
```

Just a reminder that each comma adds a blank space.

So, for your problem, you just have to add the variable **balance** on the print instruction, like this

```
#Your instruction
print ("Your expenses are within budget by $")

#The solution
print ("Your expenses are within budget by $",balance)
```

However, you will get something like this

```
>>Your expenses are within budget by $ -15.0
```

I guess you want the number before the dollar sign, so you will have to put that at the end, as i did with the ! sign on the example

```
#Previous sentence
print ("Your expenses are within budget by $", balance)

#With $ sign at the end
print ("Your expenses are within budget by", balance,"$")
```